# How to display content individually when clicking on a user in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

When clicking on a username, I want to display the information individually for that specific user.

I have tried using the `handleShow` function, which toggles from false to true, so I can display or hide the content.

The problem is when I click on a user al three divs are displayed and when the show state is false there is no content showing, which is good, but I have a black line coming from the div.

I have tried using display: none on the div, but then when I click on a username, no content is displayed.

What is the solution to display and hide the content only for a specific username and to have a display: none when the show state is false?

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow((prevShow) => !prevShow);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Data failed to fetch");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoaded && (
        <>
          <Users data={data} handleShow={handleShow} />
          <Card data={data[0]} show={show} />
          <Card data={data[1]} show={show} />
          <Card data={data[2]} show={show} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}



const Users = (props) => {
  const { data, handleShow } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handleShow}>
        {data[0].name}
      </p>
      <p style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handleShow}>
        {data[1].name}
      </p>
      <p style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handleShow}>
        {data[2].name}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;



const Card = (props) => {
  const { data, show } = props;

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", textAlign: "center" }}>
      {show && (
        <>
          {" "}
          <h3>{data?.id}</h3>
          <h3>{data?.username}</h3>
          <h3>{data?.email}</h3>{" "}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't render anything if your `show` is `false`. Black line is shown because of the border.

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const { data, show } = props;

  if (!show) return (<></>);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", textAlign: "center" }}>
          {" "}
          <h3>{data?.id}</h3>
          <h3>{data?.username}</h3>
          <h3>{data?.email}</h3>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ok, but I want a border, so how can I have a border when the content is displayed but not showing the black line from the borders when the state is false?

Comment: Can you include a sample diagram to understand your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your state to not only capture whether any user is shown but the selected index (-1 if no user shown). So `handleShow` should get a parameter for the index as well.

The `Card` component should not know whether it is shown or not but you should embed the `Card` component only when a user is selected (i.e. selected index >= 0). When selected index is -1, output no `Card` component and if a user is selected embed just one. Pass the data of the user to show.

Answer (score 0):

When you set "show", all your Card-Elements get the new value in the next render. So all Cards are always shown or not shown. You should instead give each card an index and set the Show-Variable to the index, that should be shown. If the index is -1 or null, no card is shown at all.
To achieve this, you could map your array to the Cards:

```
data.map((item, index) => {show === index && <Card data={item} />})
```

Side note: When you set states with arrays or objects, you should always create a new instance to avoid side effects. So if you set your data-array, do it like this:

```
setData([...data]);
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the full code as a working example:

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import Users from "./Users";

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(-1);

    const handleShow = (index) => {
        setShow(show === index ? -1 : index);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Data failed to fetch");
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setData([...data]);
                setIsLoaded(true);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {isLoaded && (
                <>
                    <Users data={data} handleShow={handleShow} />
                    {data.map((item, index) => show === index && <Card data={item} />)}
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Explanation: Your Card items are mapped from the data. The Card, and only one, is shown, when the show-State is matching the selected index. Please note the handleShow-function: If the index is already selected, a second click on the same entry will reset the show-State to -1, so that the Card is closed.

**Users.js**

```
const Users = (props) => {
    const { data, handleShow } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item, index) => (
                <p style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handleShow.bind(this, index)}>
                    {item.name}
                </p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Users;
```

The data-array has been mapped here also, so that every entry in the list is connected with the Array-index (see handleShow.bind(this, index).

**Card.js**

```
const Card = (props) => {
    const { data } = props;

    return (
        <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", textAlign: "center" }}>
            <>
                {" "}
                <h3>{data?.id}</h3>
                <h3>{data?.username}</h3>
                <h3>{data?.email}</h3>{" "}
            </>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

No changes here, besides getting the "show"-option out, because we don't need that here.

Comment: Can you help me with the full example? Im kinda new in this, and I`m a little confused...

Comment: I  updated my post with a working example and some basic explanation. Please reach out to me, if you need additional clarification.

Comment: Yes, I would need a little more explanation, if you have some time maybe we could talk on discord ?

Comment: sure, could you give me your discord handle please?

Comment: Sent a Request. I suggest you remove the ID from your comment now.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the state "`show`" to a higher level in `App` component like this:

```
return (
        <div className="App">
          {isLoaded && (
            <>
              <Users data={data} handleShow={handleShow} />
              {show && <Card data={data[0]} />}
              {show && <Card data={data[1]} />}
              {show && <Card data={data[2]} />}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      );
```

Then when `show` is `false` the component will not be displayed in its entirety.

Comment: Could you write a full example with the function too so I can analyze it and understand it better, please?

Answer (score -1):

```
    export default function App() {
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
      const [show, setShow] = useState(null);
    
      const handleShow = (e) => {
        setShow(e);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error("Data failed to fetch");
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            setData(data);
            setIsLoaded(true);
          });
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          {isLoaded && (
            <>
              {data.map((val,idx) =><> <Users data={val} handleShow={()=>handleShow(idx)} />
<Card val={val} show={show} idx={idx}/></>
)}
              
            
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    
    
    const Users = (props) => {
      const { val, handleShow } = props;
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={()=>handleShow()}>
            {val.name}
          </p>
          
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Users;
    
    
    
    const Card = (props) => {
      const { val, show,idx } = props;
    
      return (
        <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", textAlign: "center",display:{`${idx}===show?block:none `}}}>
         
              
              <h3>{val.id}</h3>
              <h3>{val.username}</h3>
              <h3>{val.email}</h3>
            
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Card;
```

Comment: you can display it conditionally using id or index of data[idx].id ,if show value is equal to the id or index of data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).